# matrix function not able to compile ada "declarations must come before "begin"

Tags: matrix, ada

Hi so I'm very new to ada but it doesn't seem to like this code that I wrote, I keep having this error even though it looks fine.

```
Compile
   [Ada]          main.adb
main.adb:17:09: error: declarations must come before "begin"
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

here is the code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;  use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Linear_Algebra;

procedure main is

  type Square_Matrix is array(Integer range <>, Integer range <>) of Float;
  
  function Determinant(matrix : in Square_Matrix) return Float is
    (Ada.Numerics.Linear_Algebra.Determinant(matrix));

  function Adjoint(matrix : in Square_Matrix) return Square_Matrix is
    result : Square_Matrix := matrix;
    dimension : Integer := matrix'Length;
  begin
    for i in 1 .. dimension loop
      for j in 1 .. dimension loop
        temp : Square_Matrix(dimension - 1, dimension - 1);
        for m in 1 .. dimension - 1 loop
          for n in 1 .. dimension - 1 loop
            if m < i and n < j then
              temp(m, n) := matrix(m, n);
            elsif m < i and n >= j then
              temp(m, n) := matrix(m, n + 1);
            elsif m >= i and n < j then
              temp(m, n) := matrix(m + 1, n);
            else
              temp(m, n) := matrix(m + 1, n + 1);
            end if;
          end loop;
        end loop;
        sign : Integer := (if (i + j) mod 2 = 0 then 1 else -1);
        result(j, i) := sign * Determinant(temp);
      end loop;
    end loop;
    return result;
  end Adjoint;

  matrix : Square_Matrix(1 .. 6, 1 .. 6) := ((2.0, -2.0, 4.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0),
                                             (1.0, 0.0, 4.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                             (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                                             (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                             (3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 2.0),
                                             (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 4.0));
  adjoint_matrix : Square_Matrix(1 .. 6, 1 .. 6);

begin
  adjoint_matrix := Adjoint(matrix);
  
  Put_Line("Original Matrix:");
  for i in matrix'Range(1) loop
    for j in matrix'Range(2) loop
      Put(Float'Image(matrix(i, j)), 4, 2);
    end loop;
    New_Line;
  end loop;
  
  Put_Line("Adjoint Matrix:");
  for i in adjoint_matrix'Range(1) loop
    for j in adjoint_matrix'Range(2) loop
      Put(Float'Image(adjoint_matrix(i, j)), 6, 2);
    end loop;
    New_Line;
  end loop;
  
end main;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the problem with `sign` - which you would have come across as soon as you’d fixed the code in line with @Zerte’s answer - you have

```ada
sign : Integer := (if (i + j) mod 2 = 0 then 1 else -1);
result(j, i) := sign * Determinant(temp);
```

You’re not allowed to declare something (here, `sign`) in the middle of code; the structure you would use would be a *declare block*,

```ada
declare
   sign : Integer := (if (i + j) mod 2 = 0 then 1 else -1);
begin
   result(j, i) := sign * Determinant(temp);
end;
```

What I was suggesting (and, apologies for not noticing that you were already using a conditional expression) was

```ada
result(j, i) := Determinant(temp)
   * (if (i + j) mod 2 = 0 then 1 else -1);
```

or maybe

```ada
result(j, i) := (if (i + j) mod 2 = 0 
                 then Determinant(temp)
                 else -Determinant(temp));
```

Personally, I’d probably just have used an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `temp :=` and the code that uses `temp` into a `declare ... begin ... end;` block.

Comment: Likewise with `sign`. Though you could use a conditional expression ([ARM 4.5.7](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-5-7.html))

Comment: Hi @Zerte thanks for helping but is there anyway you can give the full code? I'm very new to ada and not sure what you meant. 

Thanks!

Comment: @SimonWright, can you provide your suggested change? I'm not entirely sure how to do it. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best guess of what you were trying to do. In addition, if you use Community GNAT, compiler it with `-gnat2022` switch.

```
with Ada.Text_Io;
with Ada.Numerics.Real_Arrays;

procedure Main is

    use Ada;
    use Numerics;
    use Real_Arrays;
    use Text_IO;

    function Adjoint (Matrix : in Real_Matrix)
      return Real_Matrix is
        Result : Real_Matrix := Matrix;
        Sign   : Integer     := Integer'Last;
    begin
        for I in Matrix'range(1) loop
            for J in Matrix'range(2) loop
                declare
                    Temp : Real_Matrix := Matrix;
                begin
                    for M in Matrix'First(1) .. Matrix'Last(1) - 1 loop
                        for N in Matrix'First(1) .. Matrix'Last(1) - 1 loop
                            if M < I and N < J then
                                Temp(M, N) := Matrix(M, N);
                            elsif M < I and N >= J then
                                Temp(M, N) := Matrix(M, N + 1);
                            elsif M >= I and N < J then
                                Temp(M, N) := Matrix(M + 1, N);
                            else
                                Temp(M, N) := Matrix(M + 1, N + 1);
                            end if;
                        end loop;
                    end loop;
                    Sign := (if (I + J) mod 2 = 0 then 1 else - 1);
                    Result(J, I) := Float(Sign) * Determinant(Temp);
                end;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        return Result;
    end Adjoint;

    Origin_Matrix : Real_Matrix (1 .. 6, 1 .. 6)
        := ((2.0, -2.0, 4.0, -2.0, 0.0, 2.0),
        (1.0, 0.0, 4.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 2.0),
        (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 4.0));
    Adjoint_Matrix : Real_Matrix (1 .. 6, 1 .. 6);

begin

    Adjoint_Matrix := Adjoint(Origin_Matrix);

    Put_Line("Original Matrix:" & Origin_Matrix'Image);

    Put_Line("Adjoint Matrix:" & Adjoint_Matrix'Image);

end Main;
```

Comment: Yes, but OP’s wish to keep the scope of variables as short as possible is commendable!

Comment: Copyedit; format; please revert or edit if incorrect.